# Laravel Polymorphic relationship model name is stored instead of type

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, laravel-8

I'm using a polymorphic one to one relationship to have multiple types of product that share some fields in order to optimise the db structure. I have a Product parent model and a Shoe model.

The problem is that each time I store a product (both the Shoe and the Product) and the relationship happens (the productable_id is stored correctly), in the `productable_type` instead of seeing `App\Models\Shoe` I see `App\Models\Product` and I don't know where it's coming from.

Here are the relationship's methods:

In Product.php

```
public function productable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

In Shoe.php

```
public function product() {
    return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Product', 'productable');
}
```

product table migration:

```
$table->id();
$table->foreignId('product_model_id')->constrained('product_models');
$table->foreignId('owner_id')->nullable()->constrained('users')->onUpdate('cascade'); // fields for the model and the product's owner
$table->integer('productable_id');
$table->string('productable_type');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create Shoe -

```
$shoe = new Shoe();
// after assign value
$shoe->save();

// then create Product
$shoe->product()->create($yourProductData);
```

Comment: Ok, I passed an array there and it finally works! Do you have and idea on how to implement it with Backpack?